# Regex & Sublime: Replacestring

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have around 500 lines of this in my model:

```
var jobTitle: FieldInfoModel? = null
```

I want to make each line to be like this:

```
@Json(name = "job_title") var jobTitle: FieldInfoModel? = null
```

I am very noob in regex.
Im planning to copy all the lines in Sublime and do the replacement magic there.
Anyone can help me what to put in the Search and Replace fields?

Comment: Are you talking about a particular variable or all of them?

Comment: all of them. all my variables use camelCase. I want to convert them to snake case and put the @Json string in front of the field declaration

Comment: I don't think you can have regex to do the camelCase-to-underscore transformation easily.  Consider writing a little script to do the work.

Comment: If sublimetext supports case conversion in replace, then you are in luck.  You should be able to do your work with just a few replacements.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html

Comment: It's easy to be wise after the event.

Comment: revo's solution below is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a one-liner regex solution for working out the problem but can provide a two-step process in order to reach it:

### Step 1

Find: `var\s*(\w+)`

Replace with: `@Json(name = "\1") $0`

### Step 2

Find: `(@Json\(name = "|(?!\A)\G)([a-z]+)([A-Z])`

Replace with: `\1\2_\L\3`

[image: See action in GIF]

Notes:

`\L` *Causes all subsequent characters to be output in lower case, until a `\E` is found.*

`\U` *Causes all subsequent characters to be output in upper case, until a `\E` is found.*

Comment: Thanks for help @revo. But the output for Step2 is like this: @Json(name = "jobTitl_e") var jobTitle: FieldInfoModel? = null

Comment: You should set case sensitive option on from pane.

Comment: Yea ur right sir. Million thanks to you! =) You are amazing